# How to open protected pdf in react native

Tags: pdf, react-native

One of the tasks that I need to solve is reading a protected pdf using url and password in React Native.

I installed `react-native-pdf` in my project. Now I can read only unprotected pdf files.

How would you go about reading protected pdf files using the library I mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

The [latest documentation](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf/blob/a035dd0c85a810ef10d840ce70a3fc7420181c75/README.md) (v3.0.2) for the library you mentioned says you can pass a password prop:

> **password** - pdf password, if password error, will call OnError() with
>   message "Password required or incorrect password."

So you can use like so:

```
<Pdf
  source={source}
  password="somePasswordGoesHere"
  ...
/>
```

(Other props omitted)